# JWTs before decoding and after signing are different

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I am in the process of testing a migration of data from an already existing server to a new server.

Part of that is checking to make sure `JWTs` saved on the old server are being sent to the new server correctly. The process is to fetch tokens from the old server to the test server, and then send them to the new server to check to see if they exist. The old server sends `unsigned JWTs` over to my test server, and then I need to sign them in order to check them against the new server.

In order to get a signature for these tokens, running the following code:

```
// Get the object represented by the token
this.token = jwt.decode(`${this.unsignedToken}.a`)

// Turn the object into a signed token string
this.signedToken = jwt.sign(this.token, this.tokenSecret)
```

I concatenated the '.a' onto the end of the `unsignedToken` because `jwt.decode` needs a ***"signed"***" token in order to get the data back.

The problem I am having is that the unsignedToken and the `signedToken` don't have the same payload section of the `JWT`, even though they both decode to the exact same object. Because of that, the endpoint the `signedTokens` are sent to isn't able to match them up to what is on that server properly.

When I manually check the `unsigned` token against the new server's database, it does exist, but because the `signedToken` isn't the same string before the signature, the test process won't work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

Answer:

When I manually decoded the two tokens as base64 at https://www.base64decode.org/, I discovered that the `unsignedToken` included a URL that looked like "https:\/\/" while the `signedToken`'s url was "https://".

For anyone out there coming across this as well, my final solution was how I signed token:

```
this.signedToken = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(this.token).replace(/\//g, '\\/'), this.tokenSecret)
```

Comment: "don't have the same payload section of the jwt" --- how exactly are they different? It's base64, decode manually and compare.

Comment: "*even though they both decode to the exact same object*" - then their encoded values should be the same as well. Please post an example of this.

Comment: @Bergi I bet those would be JSON objects with keys in different order.

Comment: if you found an answer to your question, pls. write an answer in the answer field below instead of editing the answer into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I manually decoded the two tokens as base64 at https://www.base64decode.org/, I discovered that the unsignedToken included a URL that looked like "https:\/\/" while the signedToken's url was "https://".

For anyone out there coming across this as well, my final solution was how I signed token:

```
this.signedToken = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(this.token).replace(/\//g, '\\/'), this.tokenSecret)
```

Comment: Yes, zerkms, you're absolutely right. This was my solution for a tester, but for anyone reading this, be very careful about using this in production.